# Get Fancybox to render Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox

`#1` This is not working:

```
$('.someclass').fancybox({
  type: 'ajax',
  href: 'name_of_partial1',
})
```

`#2` This is working:

```
$('#some_id').fancybox({
  type: 'ajax',
  href: 'name_of_partial2',
})
```

Partial 1 and Partial 2 are in the same directory.  #some_id and .some_class are elements on two different actions in the same controller.

All I want to do is render a partial inside of fancybox, is using the fancybox href option the proper way to call a partial inside of the fancybox?

The error I'm getting with the second one is the fancybox pops up with "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later" and I get a 404 in the console.

When I change the href in #2 to:

```
href: 'name_of_partial1'
```

Then I see partial 1 get rendered in the fancybox.

Comment: What about `$('.someclass').fancybox()` instead of `.each()`?

Comment: Thanks, made an edit.  That is better code but I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To self:

Turns out that the href: '' option maps to the controller action.  I was getting a 404 because  name_of_partial2 had a controller action that by the same name, but there was some no-good render happening in that action that was throwing a 404